# Google Colab how to display a dataframe in a markdown cell

Tags: markdown, google-colaboratory

Google Colab how to display a dataframe in a markdown cell

I tried:

```py
  display(HTML(df_initial.to_html(index=False, border=0, classes="table table-striped")))
```

Markdown cell displays a code block with the text:
display(HTML(df_initial.to_html(index=False, border=0, classes="table table-striped")))

Answer (score 1):

You can use `to_markdown` method of dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd  

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [5, 6, 7, 8]})
print(df.to_markdown())
```

and then you will have the result like this

```
|    |   a |   b |
|---:|----:|----:|
|  0 |   1 |   5 |
|  1 |   2 |   6 |
|  2 |   3 |   7 |
|  3 |   4 |   8 |
```

which is this in markdown

|  | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 6 |
| 2 | 3 | 7 |
| 3 | 4 | 8 |

See more at: https://colab.research.google.com/github/khuyentran1401/Efficient_Python_tricks_and_tools_for_data_scientists/blob/master/Chapter3/style_dataframe.ipynb#scrollTo=d306323a

Comment: the `---:` in between makes it align right. `:---:` aligns middle and `---` is left aligning.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing backticks or you're asking about, how to show the output of a code cell inside a markdown cell. Either way, if [liap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14588461/liap) didn't answer the question clarify with more information about what is not showing properly.

Comment: I am trying to display in a markdown cell below my code/output cell, not in it. After more research, the problem appears to be with the way Google Colab renders output and not a Python/Jupyter issue.